# Must a dataset for a classifier be perfectly balanced?

Tags: machine-learning, classification

In machine learning it is generally accepted that the dataset for a binary classifier has to be balanced: EG. class 1 50%, class 0 50%.
My question is: has the dataset to be perfectly balanced (50/50)? I have a dataset with 1568 observations: class 1 is 47%, class 0 is 53%. Can this create issues?

Comment: No, it's not generally accepted in ML that data has to be balanced. However it is well known that data imbalance causes problems which can affect performance. That doesn't mean that imbalanced data should always be transformed into balanced data, since that's just solving a different problem. 47/53 is perfectly balanced, I would consider a dataset imbalanced if it's at least 75/25.

Comment: @Erwan Sorry, but in every book I read it is strongly recommended to have a balanced dataset if we are working with a classifier. The reason is that the model would be biased towards the class with the highest percentage. For example https://machinelearningmastery.com/what-is-imbalanced-classification/ Not completely sure about "that's just solving a different problem". Do you have any reference for what you say? A link or a book I can check.

Comment: Suppose we're trying to detect a rare form of cancer which happens in 0.1% of the population. If we balance the data 50/50, we're solving a different problem of detecting this type of cancer *in a population where it happens 50% of the time*. Doing this would cause the opposite bias of drastically overestimating this cancer. Solving the problem with the true distribution is different from solving it on an artificial distribution.

Comment: So yes, resampling is a valid technique to counter the bias caused by imbalanced data, but it's important to see it *as a technique meant to help training a  "less biased" classifier*, and very importantly to remember that [testing should always be done on the true distribution of the data](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/15630/64377), because it is the "real problem" to solve. I see this error being done all the time, and from the author of the link you gave I only find him mentioning this casually in the comments ...

Comment: on [this post](https://machinelearningmastery.com/tactics-to-combat-imbalanced-classes-in-your-machine-learning-dataset/). For ML experts it's obvious that you should always test on the true distribution, but beginners get easily confused: the resampling technique is easy and performs perfectly... except not necessarily on the true distribution. Anyway, you don't have an imbalance problem at 47/53, this cannot cause any bias since the classifier cannot "ignore" the minority class in this case.

Comment: @Erwan I see what you mean. I didn't mention that I was referring to the train dataset. Anyway, it's interesting what you say: differently of train, the test dataset should "mirror" the true distribution. This makes perfectly sense but it leads to other questions: how can I know what's the true distribution? Is the true distribution to be computed in the whole datase (train + test)? In my dataset I have no idea, I could use train + test to get it, but this is not necessarily the population distribution.

Comment: In theory the true distribution comes from wherever the data is collected, it's supposed to be a sample from the general population. For instance a spam classifier should be trained with a set of all the emails collected on a server over a period of time. Another way to see it is in terms of the production environment in which the classifier would be deployed (even if it's never actually deployed): what is a realistic input set in this environment.

Comment: @Erwan Well, I'm using a sample of the historical data coming from the exchange markets (NYSE and NASDAQ). I would need all the stocks in these 2 markets for the time range I am using, which is nearly impossible to get for several reasons. Don't know if you are familiar with this field, but you need to pay fees to get old data from a provider. After training the model I will think about a solution for the test dataset. Thanks a lot for your advice, it's a really good point.

Comment: It's quite rare to be able to collect *all* the past data in any domain (think text, images, video...), but usually a random sample is good enough. I don't know which task exactly you're targeting and I'm not expert at all in fintech, but I'd assume that some form of random sampling is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, having 50% class for each one, will have nice results while training the model, since the model is looking to optimise the accuracy.

*For example, imagine you have 99% class 0 and 1% class 1. When training, you will obtain a model that always classify 0, doing that, the model will obtain a general accuracy of 99%, but this is what you want? Balancing this data will help you avoid this type of "silly" models. This is an extreme case, but that's the reason why balanced class are used.*

When balancing take care of overfitting with the  minority class, so the model will learn to classify the same sample multiple times.

Finally, if you are using such a balanced data like you say **(47%, 53%) balancing is no needed**. Probably you can start balancing around 35% / 65% or something like this. Obviously, the behaviour of the data with balancing depends on the datset.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. From what I read, the main reason for balancing a dataset is to avoid that the model is biased towards the majority class (in my dataset the class 0). Anyway, you have confirmed that 47/53 means a good balancing, then you don't need to have exactly 50/50.

Comment: Ohh thank your for this extra information. Glad that my answer was useful too!